# Combining PULP with HiGHS cmd solver, stuck while writing the solution

Tags: python, windows, linear-programming, solver, pulp

Combining PULP with HiGHS cmd solver, stuck while writing the solution

I have developed MIP built with PuLP in python, using the HiGHS cmd Solver. I originally developed the entire code in Mac where it runs smoothly within seconds. Now when I am trying to run the same script in a Windows system, the solver is getting stuck at final step.
Following is the code snippet I am using for LP:

```py
        prob = pl.LpProblem("Arrangement Pl", pl.LpMaximize)
        cutVariables = pl.LpVariable.dict("cuts", cuts, 0, None, pl.LpInteger)

        prob += pl.lpSum([WidthOrder[i] * cutVariables[i] for i in cuts])
        prob += pl.lpSum([WidthOrder[i] * cutVariables[i] for i in cuts]) <= Deckle
        prob += pl.lpSum([cutVariables[i] for i in cuts]) <= maxCuts
        for i in cuts:
            prob += cutVariables[i] <= OrderDict[i]

        solver = pl.HiGHS_CMD(path=path_to_HiGHS)
        result = prob.solve(solver)
```

The script is stuck at prob.solve() line. Following is the output message, I get before the script stucks forever

```
Running HiGHS 1.5.3 [date: 1970-01-01, git hash: 45a127b78]
Copyright (c) 2023 HiGHS under MIT licence terms
MIP  Arrangement_Pl-pulp has 3 rows; 1 cols; 3 nonzeros; 1 integer variables
Presolving model
0 rows, 0 cols, 0 nonzeros
0 rows, 0 cols, 0 nonzeros
Presolve: Optimal

Solving report
  Status            Optimal
  Primal bound      400
  Dual bound        400
  Gap               0% (tolerance: 0.01%)
  Solution status   feasible
                    400 (objective)
                    0 (bound viol.)
                    0 (int. viol.)
                    0 (row viol.)
  Timing            0.01 (total)
                    0.01 (presolve)
                    0.00 (postsolve)
  Nodes             0
  LP iterations     0 (total)
                    0 (strong br.)
                    0 (separation)
                    0 (heuristics)
Writing the solution to Arrangement_Pl-pulp.sol
```

I am fairly new to this and any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like it solved the problem, got "optimal" status (good) and a value.  What exactly is going wrong?  What (specifically) do you mean by "writing the solution"?  I suggest editing your post and showing the lines of code where you are trying to write the solution